# Vector spaces, bases and components

Tags: vector-spaces

Consider the usual vector space $\mathbb{R^2}$.

The vectors are ordered couple of real numbers.
The ordered couple as a whole is a vector in $\mathbb{R^2}$, the first and second elements of the couple are not the component of the vector, because I haven't chose a basis yet.

For example these are vector:

$\mathbf{(5,6)}$

$\mathbf{(2,8)}$

If I chose a basis, for example the vectors $\mathbf{(0,1)}$ and $\mathbf{(1,0)}$ in THIS ORDER I can represent any vector of $\mathbb{R^2}$ using an ordered couple of real numbers called first and second components of the vector.

So $\mathbf{(5,6)}$ is represented by $(6,5)$

and

$\mathbf{(2,8)}$ is represented by $(8,2)$

The first vector of the basis $\mathbf{(0,1)}$ is represented by $(1,0)$

Pratically the couples are reversed.

I have always found this problem a bit confused.

What do you think ?

Comment: You're right in what you say, but the question as posed is too broad to answer. Do you have any specific question?

Comment: I don't have any specific question. I just wanted to know if my reasoning was correct.

Comment: You are right. A vector is a fixed object that can have different coordinates according to the basis you choose. In this sense coordinates are superficial  and the essence of the vector is it's relative angle and size respect to other vectors.

This is an important fact in special relativity, where changing from one inertial frame to another is equivalent to a change of basis. In this case the vector is the same for all inertial observers, but the coordinates according to each of them is different, this is why time and space measurements (*i.e* coordinates) change for different observers.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly I too had this problem intially. Here is how I look at it. Suppose I tell you $(x,y)$ is a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then it is assumed that some basis exists (i.e.  a point and two perpendicular unit vectors the x and y axis). Now we usually call this **the standard basis** $e_1,e_2$ the coordinates of this basis are $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ respectively. Notice the fixed axis $e_1, e_2$ initially is crucial. From here you get all the other **coordinates**. Then as you have done you can change the basis to $\{e_2 ,e_1\}$ and show that the coordinate $(1, 0)$ changes to  $(0,1)$. You can trip up undergrads with this stuff.

Comment: But if I pick the cartesian product $\mathbb{R^2}$ and I define on it a structure of vector space, an element of the space is already a vector as a whole, whitout any bases or coordinates

Comment: What is your basis. If you say $\{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$ then this is just the same as the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Cartesian coordinates. If you say the basis is $\{(1,3), (2,5)\}$ then this is nothing but the transformed Cartesian coordinate. You need to ask yourself what are coordinates. Once you fix your ordered basis then the coordinates represent the coefficients of the ordered basis in the linear representation of a vector.

Comment: To work in a vector space, I don't necessarily have to fix a basis for using coordinates